# node.js "table" package - auto adjust width

Tags: node.js

is there way to set total width of table on this module?
https://github.com/gajus/table

I found way to set width per column, but what I want is auto-adjust column by its content length.
I think that feature is already exists, but It forces to console's width, no adjustable options.

[image: description]

n1 text should on left, and n2 text should on right.